# Migration of Azure DevOps between two Azure CSP subscriptions

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azureportal

I have two Azure Cloud Solution Provider subscriptions and Azure DevOps project created around two/three years ago when it was called Visual Studio Team Services. DevOps resources (organization and project) reside on Azure for billing purposes. I want to move DevOps resources to new subscription, but cannot because of insufficient permissions - I'm missing **AccountSubscriptionChange** permission - how do I get it? I granted myself all permissions available in DevOps.

Answer (score 0):

Create service desk ticker for Microsoft Azure support.